# Deployed SWF not accessible in Firefox

Tags: apache-flex, deployment, flash, swfobject

I'm using `swfobject.js` to <del>deploy</del> load my flex applet. Unfortunately, while I'm able to run/debug in Firefox via Flash Builder, I cannot access the deployed applet via its URL -- the applet doesn't load/start. I can access the deployed applet via its URL from both IE 8 and Chrome 7. Anyone what could be causing this issue in Firefox? Below are the swfobject code and the produced object tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        <!-- For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. -->
        var swfVersionStr = "10.0.0";
        <!-- To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. -->
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "white";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "FlexUi";
        attributes.name = "FlexUi";
        attributes.align = "middle";
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "FlexUi.swf", "flashContent",
            "100%", "100%",
            swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
            flashvars, params, attributes);
                    <!-- JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object. -->
                    swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
    };
</script>


<div>
   <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="FlexUi" name="FlexUi" align="middle" data="FlexUi.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
   ...
   </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your swfobject code too?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using swfobject.js to deploy my
>   flex applet

SWObject.js is a JavaScript file; and JavaScript files are just text.

To "Deploy" a Flex application usually means to export a release build, and then moves all the files from your development machine to a production machine.

There is no way to "deploy" anything with swObject.js.

Most people export a release build using Flash Builder (or other tooling) and then upload to the production machine using FTP or across a network.

You may be deploying your application with some JavaScript and other HTML files including swfObject.js.  If so, I strongly suggest you look at the generated index.html page generated in your 'release build' folder.  See what is different there that is not in your "Web Page."   Based on what you've shown us of your web page integration script ,it is not using swfObject.

Here is the Flex 4 default HTML Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
    <!-- 
    Smart developers always View Source. 

    This application was built using Adobe Flex, an open source framework
    for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
    Flash Player or to desktops via Adobe AIR. 

    Learn more about Flex at http://flex.org 
    // -->
    <head>
        <title>${title}</title>         
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!-- Include CSS to eliminate any default margins/padding and set the height of the html element and 
             the body element to 100%, because Firefox, or any Gecko based browser, interprets percentage as 
             the percentage of the height of its parent container, which has to be set explicitly.  Initially, 
             don't display flashContent div so it won't show if JavaScript disabled.
        -->
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
            html, body  { height:100%; }
            body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:auto; text-align:center; 
                   background-color: ${bgcolor}; }   
            #flashContent { display:none; }
        </style>

        <!-- Enable Browser History by replacing useBrowserHistory tokens with two hyphens -->
        <!-- BEGIN Browser History required section ${useBrowserHistory}>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history/history.js"></script>
        <!${useBrowserHistory} END Browser History required section -->  

        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!-- For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. --> 
            var swfVersionStr = "${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision}";
            <!-- To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. -->
            var xiSwfUrlStr = "${expressInstallSwf}";
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            params.quality = "high";
            params.bgcolor = "${bgcolor}";
            params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
            params.allowfullscreen = "true";
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = "${application}";
            attributes.name = "${application}";
            attributes.align = "middle";
            swfobject.embedSWF(
                "${swf}.swf", "flashContent", 
                "${width}", "${height}", 
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                flashvars, params, attributes);
            <!-- JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object. -->
            swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- SWFObject's dynamic embed method replaces this alternative HTML content with Flash content when enough 
             JavaScript and Flash plug-in support is available. The div is initially hidden so that it doesn't show
             when JavaScript is disabled.
        -->
        <div id="flashContent">
            <p>
                To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 
                ${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision} or greater is installed. 
            </p>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://"); 
                document.write("<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='" 
                                + pageHost + "www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a>" ); 
            </script> 
        </div>

        <noscript>
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="${width}" height="${height}" id="${application}">
                <param name="movie" value="${swf}.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="${swf}.swf" width="${width}" height="${height}">
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
                    <p> 
                        Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or Adobe Flash Player version
                        ${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision} or greater is not installed.
                    </p>
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </noscript>     
   </body>
</html>
```